# How to config and access MySQL database in Zend Framework?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I am new to Zend Framework.

I try to access MySQL database by

```
    $db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(
        [
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'pass',
            'dbname' => 'database'
        ]
    );
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM table_name';
    $this->view->rec = $this->db->fetchAll($query);
```

On every controller to access database fine. (I want Single Config.)

So, i try via **Bootstrap** config,

```
   $this->bootstrap('db');
    switch (APPLICATION_ENV) {

        case 'development' :
            // this allows you to profile your queries through the firebug console
            $profiler = new Zend_Db_Profiler_Firebug('System Queries');
            $profiler->setEnabled(true);
            $this->getPluginResource('db')->getDbAdapter()->setProfiler($profiler);
            break;

        case 'production' :
            // if you use meta caching in production, which you should :)
            // Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultMetadataCache($this->_cache);
            break;
    }
```

How to access this Instance to **retrieve** data from "**table**" ?

Or any other solutions are there ?

Thanks in Advance !

Answer (score 0):

Try to setup the default adapter via Adapter Factory

```php
$db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
'host'     => BASEHOST,
'username' => BASEUSR,
'password' => BASEPASS,
'dbname'   => BASE
));
Zend_Db_Table::setDefaultAdapter($db);
```

And now you can build a model for your table

```php
<?php
class YourTable extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract{
  protected $_name = 'table' //your table;
}
```

Finally fetch the data

```php
<?php
$model = new YourTable();
$this->view->red = $model->fetchAll();
```

The advantage of this approach is now you can decouple your *queries* and now you can integrate your custom logic right on your model.